# Performance issues in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, mysql, performance, symfony-1.4

I have a web application that is built on symfony 1.4 framework. I'm making nearly 10 DB calls per http request. I found that to process the request, it takes nearly 600-800ms on the server itself. When I put log statements to track the time spent in making DB calls, I found that it is less than 20% of total time. I then found that most of the time is being spent on converting the db resultset to PHP objects. The time taken for a select query is of the order of tens of ms but time spent in deserializing this resultset is around 8-9 times more. Any suggestions on how to optimize this?

As of now I can think of adding APC so that interpreting entire php code for every request can be avoided. I also found from few links that autoloading for every request in symfony causes slowness. Any other ways of optimizing?

Comment: Did you recognize performance issues on a development or productive system?

Comment: I found this problem on both systems.

Comment: Hm, I did never experience any problems with that even with lots more than 10 DB calls per request.

Comment: What was the approximate time spent in deserializing resultset to php objects in your application?

Comment: I have no idea, but it for sure depends on your system's configuration.

Comment: Are you sure it is the DB requests? I've found that majority of the time is spent in a sfForward process or rendering the PHP templates.

Comment: I put logs before and after doing something like UserPeer::retrieveByPK(<key>); And the time taken here was very huge. Recently I installed APC to avoid PHP code to be interpreted on every request. I saw some improvement but not good enough. When is sfForward called?

Comment: I just noticed that CPU utilization is pretty high for a single request in my application. It is 23% on average for a single request and that seems to be the killer. Any suggestions on profiling tools? I saw this one: http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof/0.9.4

Comment: @SimonCast As you said, I found that 92% of CPU cycles are spent in sfController::forward method. I ran xhprof profiler on one of my pages and got this result. Apparently this method calls sfFilterChain::execute where all the cycles are spent. When I checked the code, I didnt see anything that was very CPU intensive though. Any idea why sfFilterChain::execute is so costly?

Comment: @coder no I've not spent the time to investigate. The other area I've found is the routing can also chew time as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html#array) (assuming you are using Doctrine) hydrating to objects is more impactful on performance than hydrating to arrays. Unless you need to use business logic or modify the DB records then I've found you get a significant improvement using hydrate array.

Comment: I'm using propel. I think same is the case with Propel. The application uses lot of tables and changing to hydrating to arrays is a pretty huge change. I'm not sure if using symfony is the right choice for a website which needs to scale to nearly million page views a day.

Comment: @coder, symfony is the right choice: http://marcjschmidt.de/blog/2014/02/08/php-high-performance.html